# Why my app's process exists in task manager for a while even after I closed the application?

Tags: wpf, pinvoke, dispose

I have a WPF application and it uses serial port through p/invoke.

I noticed that in some PC (not all PCs) the process exists in task manager for a while even after the application is closed.

I'd like to debug into it, but where is the starting point? the serial port handle not closed? Maybe it's related to my implementation of IDispose?
I'm not using *using* keyword for the serial port since I'm keeping it and use it all the time.

Thanks

Edit:
I can't reproduce it on my PC, it only appears on some of my user's PC. 
I know the question is not very clear but I'm sorry it IS not clear to me now. I was just wondering if anyone has seen similar problem (why the process for a closed application exist in task manager) and give me a clue.

Serial port handle, p/invoke dll, threads are suspicious points to me now.

Comment: `the serial port handle not closed` This is not the reason that process is still running. Thread that is not stopped may be a reason.

Comment: Why don't you debug the shutdown then?

Comment: @AlexFarber Yes I used some threads, I will check if they are still running after UI is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to use a logging framework at key points in your application, you mentioned using threads, so you would need to add log messages at the entry & exit points of the thread. Also add logging to the Application object event handlers for the Closing, Closed and Exit events, something like the following in the App.cs class.

Currently I use [nLog](http://nlog-project.org/) for logging.

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs args)
 {
     base.OnStartup(args);

     var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

     mainWindow.Closing += (s, a) =>
     {
        Logger.Info("Closing main window");
     };

     mainWindow.Closed += (s, a) =>
     {
         Logger.Info("Closed main window");
     };

     Current.Exit += (s, a) =>
     {
         Logger.Info("Bye Bye!");
         LogManager.Flush();
     };

     try
     {
         mainWindow.Show();
     }
     catch (Exception exn)
     {
         Logger.Error("Failed to open main window!");
         Logger.Error(exn);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm always too focused on debugging in VS to use log files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is your implementation in code, but you can use following things:

1) Implement IDisposable on custom class in which you are using pInvoke and dispose all unmanaged resources before closing app in dispose method.

2) You can try `Application.Current.Shutdown()`

Hope above points may help.

Comment: This is just wild speculation, and not particularly helpful. There's little point answering a question that can't be answered.

Comment: @Yogesh I will try Application.Current.Shutdown()